# On type of a literal, unsigned negative number

Tags: c++, literals, unsigned

The C++ Primer says:

> We can independently specify the signedees and the size of an integral
>   literal. If the suffix contains a U, then the literal has an unsigned
>   type, so a decimal, octal or hexadecimal literal with a U suffix has
>   the smallest type of unsigned int, unsigned long or unsigned long long
>   in which the literal's value fits

When one declares

`int i = -12U;`

The way i understand it is that -12 is converted to the `unsigned` version of itself (`4294967284`) and then assigned to an `int`, making the result a very large positive number due to rollover.

This does not seem to happen. What am i missing please?

`cout << i << endl; // -12`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning the unsigned int back to a signed int, so it gets converted again.

It's like you did this:

```
int i = (int)(unsigned int)(-12);
```

Comment: Right. So -12U becomes 4294967284, then 4294967284 should be assigned to an int. Is this not how it happened?

Comment: 4294967284 is too large to fit in an int, so it wraps around back to a negative value.

Comment: Note that the effect of a conversion of an unsigned type to a signed type when the signed type is not large enough to hold the value of the unsigned type is implementation defined. Typically it will simply be whatever the processor does...

Answer (score 2):

`u` effectively binds more tightly than `-`.  You are getting `-(12u)`.

Comment: Then, what is the point of `U` if it does not affect the signedess of the literal (which happened to be negative in this example)?

Comment: Upvoted! @Jam Excerpt from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal): There are no negative integer literals. Expressions such as `-1` apply the unary minus operator to the value represented by the literal, which may involve implicit type conversions.

Answer (score 1):

`12` has type int and the value 12.

`12U` has type unsigned int and the value 12.

`-12U` has type unsigned int and the value `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` + 1 - 12.

`int i = -12U;` applies an implementation-defined conversion to convert -12U to type int.

Comment: In other words, `2^n − literal` where n is the bit width of the literal's type. Thus, on a machine with 32-bit `int`s, `-12U` is 2^32 - 12 = 4294967284.